# ViewModel notify behind code upon changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

At the moment I'm using Telerik's richtextbox and the source code I'm using is from here. http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#RichTextBox/TelerikEditor I have implemented an autocomplete box such that when items are selected, the mail merge data source is updated according to what was selected. All the code is implemented behind code (not in viewmodel). From telerik forums, it looks like the itemssource can't be bound to viewmodel.

LetterEditorViewModel.xaml.cs

```
private void RadAutoCompleteBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var items = Collection.Where(x => RecipientsAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItems.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id);
    radRichTextBox.Document.MailMergeDataSource.ItemsSource = items.ToList();
}
```

I am programmatically populating the autocomplete box on the viewmodel side of the application. When I do that, the mail merge buttons aren't available, they are only available when OnSelectionChange is called. I'm wondering is there another way to trigger OnSelectionChange from the viewmodel side of the application or another way to populate the mail merge data source, hopefully MVVM. Telerik forums has nothing on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the view model can raise routed events.  Let's take a look at some code parts to show the concept.

This code would go in the control...

```
 private void NotifyListeners()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(RegisteredListeners);
        RaiseEvent(args);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The RoutedEvent registered Listeners using a tunneling strategy
    // </summary>
    public static readonly RoutedEvent RegisteredListeners =
     EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("RoutedEventListener", RoutingStrategy.Tunnel,
     typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyControl));

    /// <summary>
    /// Event Handler registration
    /// </summary>
    public event RoutedEventHandler OnNewMessageReceived
    {
        add { AddHandler(RegisteredListeners, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(RegisteredListeners, value); }
    }

  /// <summary>
  /// Called when a command is set and all Registered Listeners are notified
  /// </summary>
  public static EventHandler<EventArgs> OnNotifyNewMessage;
```

With this handler...could be in CTOR of control...

```
       OnNotifyNewMessage = (o, s) =>
        {
            NotifyListeners();
        };
```

To raise the events from the view model this would do it.

```
MyControl.OnNotifyNewMessage("Message Helpers 1360", new EventArgs());
```

Routed Events contain no easy way to "integrate".  So you can set up an eventhandler to tell the control to notify all listeners using either a bubble or tunneling strategy...  Just make sure that in the end the routed event is marked as handled=true to stop further progression.

Comment: Hi @John Peters, MessageEventArgs and Router is not recognized, may I ask what reference are those referring to?

Comment: And Router to RoutedEvent ?

Comment: Code has been updated to reflect a working solution.